# Get aggregated transaction information over last 12 months in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
ID#     transaction_amount    transaction_yr_mon
12345   20                    202007
23455   200                   202008
12345   34                    202007
```

I want to get the following:

```
ID#    Number_of_transactions_in last_12_months   total_transaction_amount  
12345  2                                          54
```

I have no idea how to start to do this in SQL please advise on what a possible query might be!

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,count(id) as Number_of_transactions_in last_12_months,sum(transaction_amount) as total_transaction_amount  
from tablename group by id
```

or

```
select id,count(id) as Number_of_transactions_in last_12_months,sum(transaction_amount) as total_transaction_amount  
from tablename group by id,transaction_yr_mon
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID 
       , count(*) Number_of_transactions_in_last_12_month
       , sum(transaction_amount) total_transaction_amount
from table t
where transaction_yr_mon >= to_char(now() - interval '12 month','YYYYMM') 
group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to filter one aggregation in the `select`:

```
select id,
       count(*) filter (where transaction_yr_mon >= to_char(now() - interval '12 month', 'YYYYMM')),
       sum(transaction_amount)
from t
group by id;
```

Of course, if you want the total to be filtered by the last 12 months as well, it is simpler to move the logic to the `where` clause:

```
select id, count(*), sum(transaction_amount)
from t
where transaction_yr_mon >= to_char(now() - interval '12 month', 'YYYYMM')
group by id;
```